# Another Wordpress Installation in a Subfolder

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem in my Wordpress installation. The root folder of my server has a working wordpress application. And then, I created another folder within the root and installed another wordpress. My folder structure is like this

- ROOT

  - wp-admin
  - wp-content
  - ..........
  - new

    - wp-admin
    - wp-content
    - ..........

So, basically, I have two wordpress installation, one in the root and another in a subfolder. Going to http://example.com, the main wordpress app works without any errors. Going to http://example.com/new, it also works. The problem is, clicking a post inside the new app redirect me to the main app. Clicking a post with a link http://example.com/new/post shows an error page. But that post exists within the new app.

Each app has their own DB

Thanks for responses!

Comment: are you using same DB for both installation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You there is some problem in your permalink. check your permalink or, update your new database , as of now your database fetch values from old database...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your dashboard and choose Settings -> General

Then make sure that `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` correctly point to your `new` folder, that is `http://example.com/new`.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your Phpmyadmin panel.
- Navigate to your second wordpress database and open table named as "`options`".
- At column
  "`option_name`" find two rows containing data "`siteurl`" and "`home`".
- Check column "`option_value`" at these two rows.
- They should contain url of your second wordpress installation.

Like `http://example.com/new`